# Alpine apk info for exact package names

Tags: package-management, alpine-linux

I'm trying to get the installed size of all installed packages in Alpine Linux. Unfortunately `apk info` doesn't seem to let me specify exact package names:

```
A ~# apk info -s vim
vim-8.2.0-r0 installed size:
29790208

gvim-8.2.0-r0 installed size:
30085120

A ~# apk info vim-8.2.0-r0
A ~#
```

I only have vim installed, but gvim is listed too. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apk list vim`, only return exact matched package.Both vim and gvim provide vim, you can only install one of them.